# Indexing document metadata and its content separately in haystack

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I am new to solr and haystack, I am indexing document (pdf/txt etc) and would like to know is it possible to index just the metadata immediately after save and then pass the indexing of document content to celery task.

Currently i am using realtimesignalprocessor to do immediate indexing, i am thinking just to index metadata of file at this time and then adding content indexing to queue to handle by celery task.

Is it possible ? if yes how to do so?